# is there a general accounting system database schema which i can use?

Tags: database-schema, accounting

i require a generic accounting system database schema is there any sites which provide this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database schema design for a double entry accounting system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494343/database-schema-design-for-a-double-entry-accounting-system)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that would be difficult find something out of the box (it's quite complicated, starting from basic question: which country tax law you are targeting) , but you can look at http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/ , searching at least inspiration ;)

Comment: im doing this project as for my final yr so it doesnt hav to be perfect. i dont think ill be implementing any taxation too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find a good answer in this [question answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494343/database-schema-design-for-a-double-entry-accounting-system) , It is about the double entry system , There is links and a simple data model in there. Please check.