# looking for a simple database design for accounts receivable

Tags: sql, accounting, invoices, receipt

I am in the process of adding accounts receivable to one of my webapps. Essentially, I want to be able to create sales invoices and record payments received.

The reports, I generate are

- statement with balance outstanding
- invoice
- receipt

To create a statement, I was thinking of doing a union of receipts and invoices ordered by date.

I also need to cater for `refunds/credits`, which i am doing by refund = receipts with a negative amount, and credit = invoice with a negative amount.

All the invoices/receipts are exported to a full accounting package (so don't require double entry system at this end)

What i have come up with is

```
INVOICES
id
customer_id
total
tax_amount
reference
user_id
created

INVOICE_LINES
id
invoice_id
description
qty
unit_price
total
tax_amount

RECEIPTS
id
customer_id
reference
internal_notes
amount
user_id
created
```

Is there anything that i am missing?

Would a single transactions table be simpler instead of having separate invoice/receipt tables?

Another thought, is it normal to link a receipt to an invoice? what if a receipt was for multiple invoices.

Any advice appreciated (simplicity is the goal)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at the ["Library of Free Data Models"](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/) from DatabaseAnswers.org

They have many basic designs that should inspire you.
For example ["Accounting Systems"](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/accounting_systems/index.htm)

Comment: this one is of interest, i have emailed barry to see if the more detailed version of the design is available. thanks http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/invoices_and_payments/index.htm

Comment: @bumperbox: This site is excellent to start you off. You may need to donate :-) I have no link to the site but the guy does all this for the love of it...

Comment: I only have one problem. Seeing the design from the comment, there are no table that defines the amount. Where can I put the amount for each transaction?

Comment: @Mark, the model is only showing key fields. Add whatever other fields you deem necessary, such as TransAmount in Financial_Transactions.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this similar question [Database schema design for a double entry accounting system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494343/database-schema-design-for-a-double-entry-accounting-system) . I came across it googling for 'bookkeeping database design' as I reckon you'll easily find free or relatively low-priced databases already exist - as you say - simplicity is the goal.