# Accounting database schema

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, accounting

I'm looking for existing andp properly designed accounting database schema rather than develop it from scratch. I know that there are single-entry and double-entry accounting and I prefer to use double-entry one.

Can someone point me in the right direction or provide with a link to right resource?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494343/database-schema-design-for-a-double-entry-accounting-system

Comment: Did you find any solid schema which suit you needs? Please answer your quiestion if Yes. I'm looking for that too.. Thanks,